# Compiled files in cmake

Tags: cmake

I Have configured a list of folders which will be considered for a build in a CMAKE file.But inside those folders there are few source file which will not taken for compilation while build.
How can I generate the list of files( C and C++ Source files) that are only considered for compilation for build using CMAKE.?

Comment: 1) Have you tried reading a CMake tutorial? 2) Without your code it's impossible for anybody to tell you what's wrong or missing.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Please tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. 
Also see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple subfolders, you can add them by add_subdirectory and modify the CMakeLists.txt in the subfolders by accessing the ${SOURCE_FILES} variable in the parent scope by

```
SET(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
                 subFolder/yetAnotherFile.cpp
                 PARENT_SCOPE
                 )
```

In the main folder (the folder that includes the subfolder), you add the following to the CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(subFolder/
add_executable(program ${SOURCE_FILES})
```